# Create a selection from a selection

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table

In QGIS 3.10, is there a way to click into selected features in the attribute table and make a selection from a selection, like in ArcGIS?

Comment: Using Ctrl+LMB you may unselect single features.

Comment: In the Select by Expression Dialog, you have a button `Select features`. You'll see a little arrow next to it, if you click it, you'll see the options `Remove from the current selection` and `Filter the current selection`.

Comment: @Erik please define "LMB"

Comment: @Stu LMB typically refers to left mouse button in shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't possible like in ArcGIS but It is possible to create new selections using filters and expressions, ore remove from the selection. you can find the documentation here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection

If you need the possibility to select inside a selection by clicking you can do a "feature request" on the GitHub QGIS Project